# Pandas count rows between in two date columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need count the rows has between the columns date_from and date_to, example:

I have this DataFrame:
date_from     date_to

```
0    2017-07-01  2017-07-03
1    2017-07-01  2017-07-05
2    2017-07-02  2017-07-04
3    2017-07-03  2017-07-04
```

I need count how rows has between the columns date_from and date_to, example:

```
              count
date
2017-07-01    2
2017-07-02    3
2017-07-03    3
2017-07-04    1
```

I has trying with:

```
df.groupby(['date_from','date_to']).size()
```

but the pandas count a row once

**EDIT:**

I need count how many rows are between two dates, 
The dataframe that only have one row with this:

```
    date_from     date_to
0 2017-07-01    2017-07-03
```

have this output:
2017-07-01    1
2017-07-02    1

Comment: There have been 3 answers so far in which the people answering have deleted their answers.  I cannot speak for the others, but I deleted my answer because I'm confused about what you want.  Can you please make it clearer by showing how you got from your sample dataframe to your expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting dates in a range set by pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36341081/counting-dates-in-a-range-set-by-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @piRSquared i edited the question, i hope the extra explanation help, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

- first substract one day from `date_to`
- reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and create `DatetimeIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
- [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) by `day`s and aggregate by [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.ffill.html) or [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.count.html)
- last use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) or [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

---

```
df['date_to'] = df['date_to'] - pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='d')
df = df.stack().rename_axis(('a','b')).reset_index(name='c').set_index('c')
df = df.groupby('a').resample('d').ffill().groupby('c').size().reset_index(name='a')
print (df)
           c  a
0 2017-07-01  2
1 2017-07-02  3
2 2017-07-03  3
3 2017-07-04  1
```

Similar solution:

```
df['date_to'] = df['date_to'] - pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='d')
df = df.stack().rename_axis(('a','b')).reset_index(name='c').set_index('c')
df = df.groupby('a').resample('d')['b'].size().reset_index()
#
df = df['c'].value_counts().sort_index().rename_axis('a').reset_index()
print (df)
           a  c
0 2017-07-01  2
1 2017-07-02  3
2 2017-07-03  3
3 2017-07-04  1
```

And another solution with [`itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html):

```
df['date_to'] = df['date_to'] - pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='d')

df=pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Index,
                        pd.date_range(r.date_from, r.date_to)) for r in df.itertuples()])
      .reset_index()

df = df['index'].value_counts().sort_index().rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='c')
print (df)
           a  c
0 2017-07-01  2
1 2017-07-02  3
2 2017-07-03  3
3 2017-07-04  1
```